# adding comments like facebook with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I'm developing an `blog` using `ASP.NET`, and I want that the user can be able to add comments.

So I want to implement the idea of `facebook` on adding comments.

The comment will be stored in the `database`, so I will be able to load it with the page if the user goes to another web page.

You have any idea how can I do this thing ( Ajax, Javascript, jQuery, Ajax Toolkit ) ?

**EDIT:**

I found this :

```
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<p>

<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>

</p>

<input type="submit" value="Commenter"/>

<br />

</form>

<p>Add some Test to the page</p>

</body>
```

and `script.js` :

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {

document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = addNode;

}

function addNode() {

var inText = document.getElementById("textArea").value;

var newText = document.createTextNode(inText);

var newGraf = document.createElement("p");

newGraf.appendChild(newText);

var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

docBody.appendChild(newGraf);

return false;

}
```

But how can I save the comment in the database, because an input button can't do this !

Comment: You're going to need more than Javascript, that's for sure. It can't do databases natively.

Comment: Ajax and Ajax toolkit are nearly synonyms, they are usually used for functionality and "prettifying" like timers, asynchronous postbacks, etc. You'd worry about this part last, and get your core model up first.

Comment: And, ASP.NET natively supports database operations, you should have no issues getting your core model just with that and your database. Though, JQuery enthusiasts will shout with raised-fists "Use JQuery!" at you, it's easily possible to do this sort of thing without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you are using GridView to display those blog post, simply add a template field into the Gridview. Inside the template filed, you put a Textbox and a Button.

When user click on the button, use your code behind to find the postID, and textbox, and save it to database, and then remember to bind the data to the gridview again.

Here is some sample code.

```
protected void btnBuy_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btnBuy = (ImageButton)sender; //Find which button is clicked.
    //If that is a button, use Button btnBuy = (Button)Sender;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnBuy.NamingContainer; //Find which gridview row     //containes the clicked button

    Label lblPostID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPostID"); //Find the post ID
    TextBox txtComment = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtComments"); //Find the textbox

    //Save the data to database.
    //Put your code here.

    //Bind the gridview with the data source which got some new data.
    GridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to use JavaScript to do this, although if you wish to do this asynchronously to provide a more responsive user experience then you will need JavaScript.

Using ASP.NET web forms, there are a number of ways this could be set up on the server side. You could use

1. **[Page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)**
2. **[ASMX web services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)**
3. **[WCF services](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html)**

And call them using JavaScript from the client side. Inside of the server side code is where you will connect to the database, perform your CRUD operation and return a response back to the client that made the AJAX call.

A note on security - you'll want to sanitise the comments and mitigate SQL injection, XSS, XSRF and other types of injection attacks. The **[Anti-XSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/20333)** (soon to be superceded by the Web Protection library) is a good tool to leverage to do this and offers a better approach to encoding than the standard encoding in ASP.NET

Comment: I'm lost in front of all these things.

Comment: let's say how can I implement comments like stackoverflow  ?

Comment: I would recommend concentrating on getting the standard postback approach working first, binding an event handler on the server side to a button control's click event to submit a comment. Once you have this working, then look to introduce AJAX into the picture.